# Putting a FragmentedTabHost in a Fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to get an application working that uses the ActionBar slider with a TabHost.  I am replacing the current Fragment with another when a menu item is selected.

```
if (fragment != null) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

The problem that I am getting is that I am unable to replace a fragment with a FramgentActivity which contains a TabHost. So my question is, is it possible to put a FragmentedTabHost inside a Fragment (instead of a FragmentedActivity)? If so, how would you implement it?